# Convert every other letter in String to uppercase, counting only characters java

Tags: java, string, capitalize

I want to convert every other letter in a string to capital. Say I have a string: "h3e5l!@lo461!28", I need to see if the character is a letter and then convert every other letter to capital. Here is my code right now but it doesn't work and I don't understand what to do to fix it.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    String a = "h3e5l!@lo461!28" ;
    System.out.println(cap(a));
}

public static String cap(String a){
    for(int i = 0; i< a.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(a.charAt(i)) && i % 2 == 0){
            a.charAt(i) = a.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StringBuilder` object to collect all the processed characters and return the `StringBuilder` object in the end.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "h3e5l!@lo461!28";

        System.out.println(cap(a));
    }

    public static String cap(String a) {
        int count = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char ch = a.charAt(i);
            // Capitalise every other letter
            if (Character.isLetter(ch) && (++count) % 2 == 0) {
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
            } else {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
h3E5l!@Lo461!28
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you can't replace individual characters in a `String`, you should instead use a `char[]` retrieved from `String#toCharArray`, like the following:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
   String a = "h3e5l!@lo461!28" ;
  
   System.out.println(cap(a));
}

public static String cap(String a){
    // count letters
    int letterCount = 0;
    char[] chars = a.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){   
        if(Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
            letterCount += 1;
            if(letterCount % 2 == 0) { // every other letter
                chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: This will return incorrect result e.g. for the given string, it will return `h3e5l!@lo461!28` which is wrong. It should return `h3E5l!@Lo461!28` as the requirement states: `convert every other letter to capital.`

Comment: You've probably meant `return new String(chars);`

Comment: @kasptom - Even after this change, it will return an incorrect result.